# How to resolve this exception

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

This Exception invoked and not able to resolved it ...

```
 Error:scalac: missing or invalid dependency detected while loading class file 'GenericCollection.class'.
 Could not access term play in package <root>,
 because it (or its dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for
 missing or conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the problematic classpath.)
 A full rebuild may help if 'GenericCollection.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of <root>.
```

Comment: Reactivemongo uses some parts of Play framework. You will need to include Play in your project.

Comment: Could you add the import that fixed your error ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message is basically saying that `GenericCollection.class` has a reference to the `_root_.play` package, but the `play` package can't be found.

You have to add a dependency to the library that provides the `play` package, which is very likely part of the play framework.

Comment: how do I do that??

Comment: How to add that?